# Masking CGContext with a CGPathRef?

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, cgpath

I am doing some drawing using a CGContext. I am currently masking the drawing using a png file like this:

```
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame.png"];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext ();
CGContextClipToMask(context, self.view.bounds, myImage.CGImage);
```

This works fine, but now I'd like to use an existing CGPathRef as my mask.
Should I look at converting the CGPathRef to a UIImage and mask as above?
If so how would I go about doing the conversion?
-OR-
Is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
CGContextAddPath(context, yourPath);
CGContextClip(context);
```

Comment: This works good for rects&ellipse. But not works for me if path is created by addArcWithCenter:radius:... And when I need just one pixel line to keep.

Comment: What should we do if we don't want it to be clipped? For example if we want to mask a custom path on an image without clipping it to the bounds of path ? @cxa